# Extract data using bs4 from a javascript text span

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

im trying to extract some data from a span that is after a text/javascript script, i tried with regex both its to fragile:
how can i get the span after text/javascript?

```
html_content = urlopen('https://www.icewarehouse.com/Bauer_Vapor_1X/descpage-V1XS7.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

price =soup.find(class_='crossout')
span = price('span')
print(span)
```

output disired:

```
 649.99 949.99
```

Comment: How are you using semicolons and commas in python?

Comment: Sorry im new and i couldn't upload the question without putting that in the code, that s the part for javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to get the minimum and maximum of the array `msrp`. In which case you can't use BS for that. Use plain re.

Try this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_content =urlopen('https://www.icewarehouse.com/Bauer_Vapor_1X/descpage-V1XS7.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml") 
pattern = re.compile("msrp.push\((.*?)\);.*msrp.push\((.*?)\);")
m = pattern.search(soup.text)
if m:
    print(m[1], m[2])
```

This uses two capturing groups to get the minimum and maximum values from the line where values are pushed into the array `msrp`.